# vscode indent full line instead of insert tab

Tags: tabs, visual-studio-code, indentation

One of my many vscode extensions must have been updated in the background. I cannot trace which one but since the tab key indent the full line instead of inserting a tab.
From what I found online, there is no way to fix this with the keymap settings?
I have tried and disabled all extensions but that doesn't fix it.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try opening up the the vscode command pallete using `ctrl+shift+p`.
Then type in `indent using spaces` and select it. This should bring up a menu where you can select the tab size.

Comment: nope sorry, I tried that first (by clicking the Tab Size icon on the bottom right, the same thing I think) but it won't change anything. If I just place my cursor in a middle of a word, pressing tab will indent the full line, instead of inserting a Tab at the cursor's position.